# jPlayer run function onclick of track name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am using jPlayer and I am wanting to run a custom function once I click on a track name to play it. How do I do this? I cannot seem to find this in any of the documentation.

```
new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jplayerContainer",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jplayerContainer"
}, [{
    title: "Waiting On The World To Change",
    mp3: "Waiting On The World To Change.mp3"
}], {
    swfPath: "jplayer/",
    supplied: "oga, mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`$.jPlayer.event.play`](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-type) event to run code when media starts to play.

```
var $jp = $('#jquery_jplayer_1');
$jp.on($.jPlayer.event.play,  function(e){
    console.log("Current track", e.jPlayer.status.media);
    console.log("Currentr track index", myPlayer.current);
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Luug0jd/) for code and demonstration.